# Parsing Specific JSON data from website and Displaying in TextView

Tags: android, json

I am looking to pull data from my websites JSON url and display only one object in the textview. I was able to parse the entire JSON array, but not the specific object.

Here's the JSON on the site:

{"id":3,"day":" an A","created_at":"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z","updated_at":"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z"}

As you can see, it's pretty simple, but basically all I want to pull is the

> "day":" an A"

and display it in my textview as "an A". Until now, I've only been able to pull the entire array.

A reference to this or any solution would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

MainActivity Class:

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parseDay);
    TextView textView1 = null;

    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject("day");
        try {
        String day =json.getString("day");
        textView1.setText(day);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //catch (JSONException e) {
         // e.printStackTrace();
        //} 
    catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and My GetMethod:

> public class GetMethod {

```
public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try { 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.xelatechnologies.com/hfdays/show.json");

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }

        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }
    finally { 
        if (in !=null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm extremely new to JSON parsing so I'm sure it is not right at all. But it's worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

```
{"id":3,"day":" an A","created_at":"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z","updated_at":"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z"}
```

As its starts from **'{'** so it is an `Object` not `Array`

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
try {
String days=json.getString("day");
textview.setText(days);
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Edited:***

```
TextView textView1;
String response;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parseDay);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);//First Initialise TextView
    GetMethod method=new GetMethod();
    response=method. getInternetData();// Then get the Json response

    try{
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(response);
        try {
        String day =json.getString("day");
        textView1.setText(day);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And dont forget to add Internet Permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Try like this.

Comment: Still doesn't work, compiles fine with no errors, just nothing displayed.

Comment: i had the internet permission before, but with the new code it force closes. i am sure it is something i am doing wrong and you are probably correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For getting data from internet you should use AsyncTask or something like this. Set day to textview in onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is a JSONObject. In java you can put that object into an JSONObject like this (You can use any serialize/deserializer you would like, many exist, for this example try org.json):

```
String json = "{\"id\":3,\"day\":\" an A\",\"created_at\":\"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-11-06T12:30:59.023Z\"}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Now you have created a json object. Next you want to set the text on the text view. The key to get your value in this case is "day". So now all you have to do is use the provided getString(String value) method on the json object.

```
final String DAY = "day";
String dayValue= "";
try {
    value = jsonObject.getString(DAY);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText(dayValue);
```